# Android Studio's stock google maps activity doesn't seem be rendering correctly in the activity_maps.xml (Render error: Unknown fragments)

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

After building a project with its MainActivity being a Google Maps activity (Android Studio's default MapsActivity), when I go to my activity_maps.xml, I face this rendering error known as "Unknown fragments". I don't know if it's normal for the maps activity to be like this or not cos I'm a newbie (don't mind plz).

[image: enter image description]

So if it's normal how am I supposed to add layouts and stuff to it (which I'm unable to) and if it's not normal then how do i fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You